# Acumatica Report Designer Repeating first record of mySQL view

Tags: acumatica

Created a view and added to DAC and can view correctly in Generic Enquiry.  However when added in Report Designer it returns correct number of rows but the data is just repeated form the first row.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your view contains CompanyID field and DAC has proper key(s) defined.

Comment: Thanks, the view does contain the CompanyID and I just added it to the DAC using Customisation Project Code but made no changes to what was automatically created.  What keys should be defined?

Comment: Actually that was the key.  Thanks again